# How to Play a protected video using mediaElement or mediaPlayerElement

Tags: win-universal-app

What's the proper way to play a video which requires authentication?

The video is hosted on a server which uses basic authentication, the credentials have to be passed on a cookie on the header.

I have tried AdaptiveMediaSource but I got an error that the server doesn't support the protocol.

I have tried this https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient/tree/master/MediaElementWithHttpClient but I got an error that Range is not supported.

Any help will be greatly appreciate it.

I'm targeting Windows 10 anniversary edition

Cheers
H

Comment: Can you share the URI hosting your video?

Answer (score 1):

I have replied your same case in MSDN.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dea09e8e-dd85-48dd-8edb-59ef150f442e/how-to-play-a-protected-video-using-mediaelement-or-mediaplayerelement?forum=wpdevelop

You can try to use WebView control to see if it can meet your requirements. The official sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView

> I have tried AdaptiveMediaSource but I got an error that the server doesn't support the protocol.

According to the official document, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming
The Adaptive Streaming feature currently supports playback of Http Live Streaming (HLS) and Dynamic Streaming over HTTP (DASH) content. For a list of supported HLS protocol tags, see [HLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/hls-tag-support) tag support. 
If your server doesn't support these protocol you cannot use the Adaptive streaming feature.

> I have tried this https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient/tree/master/MediaElementWithHttpClient but I got an error that Range is not supported.

Please see the Note in the Readme.md file of the demo.
Note: The server must support HTTP Range headers. If your server doesn't support HTTP range headers you cannot directly use the demo.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by *heroboy* in this [issue](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient/issues/4), the *Range* header request is not mandatory in the initial response, so you can try removing the following check from *HttpRandomAccessStream.cs*:

```
if (!response.Headers.ContainsKey("Accept-Ranges"))
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format(
        "HTTP server does not support range requests: {0}",
        "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5"));
}
```

But the server will still need to support *range requests*.

There is also a version of the [sample for MediaPlayerElement](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient).

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the response. It looks like I'm out of luck as the server doesn't support range requests. Any advise?